# creating generic class which will map to any class without knowing how many members class has in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, generics

I want to create generic class from any class which will map to all members in that class.
e.g.Suppose I have following 2 classes which have different number of properties

```
 class Data

{
bool  IsChecked{get;set;}
string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and one more class like

```
Class Test
{
bool IsChecked{get;set;}
string TestName{get;set;}
string TestProblem{get;set}
string TestSolution
}
```

Now I want to create class which will be generic which will map properties from above class at runtime.

```
class Generic<T>
{
//This class should map any of the above classes with all properties.
}
```

Is it possible to create such class in c#? and Can I bind properties from this Generic class to XAML in wpf?

Comment: Which class do you want to use as type parameter with `Generic<T>`? If it is `Data` or `Test`, how should `Generic<Data>` differ from `Data`? If something else: please give an example.

Comment: @Matthias, Data and Test are only examples but it can be any other class also other than these class.

Comment: @DTsawant - that didn't really answer the question, how `Generic<Data>` differs from `Data`. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Corak my problem is that I want to create one class which will be similar to any class with all members but I don't know the name of that class & members of that class.

Comment: @DTsawant - But with something like `Generic<T>` you won't get *one* class. You will get as many classes as you are using it with. The compiler will automatically create something like a `Generic_Data` class when you use it as `Generic<Data>` and a separate `Gemeric_Test` class when you use it as `Generic<Test>`. The compiler basically uses your `Generic<T>` as template and substitutes each `T` inside the classes created from it with the class you use it with. -- So you explicitly *can't* do something like `var list = new List<Generic> {new Generic<Data>(), new Generic<Test>};`

Comment: Maybe you are just looking for [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd264741.aspx).

Comment: @Corak That is not a correct description of how generics work in C#. It is closer to how templates work in C++.

Comment: @Corak yes.I want to have everything dynamic

Comment: @mikez - Yes, I know. Note the use of "something like" and "basically". The important point I wanted to make is, that `Generic<Data>` and `Generic<Test>` will be two different types which cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: @Corak That's a fine point to make, but along the way you introduce what, I think, is a misleading mental model to use when thinking about generics.

Comment: This questions is not at all clear. What is meant by "map any of the above classes with all properties"? Are you asking about reflection? code generation? or something else? Honestly, it sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @mikez I want to generate a class with other class we can say that I want to make a copy of the class but my problem is that I don't know what class type is and what & how many members are there in class.

Answer (score 0):

There is a a class library that's quite popular called "Automapper" you can add this easily to and solution and gain the functionality you need.. It will even map lists of objects not to mention it will ignore all non existent fields. And yes you could bind any object you want technically in xaml. You can create your own templates to fit your object types. Or you can use the standard xaml templates. You can find automapper with your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple like this

```
public class Generic<T>
{
    public System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] GetAllProperties()
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperties();
    }
}
```

Usage

**1.**

```
var item = new Generic<Data>();
item.GetAllProperties();
```

**2.**

```
typeof(Data).GetProperties();
```

**3.** dynamically get properties by class name in runtime

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("YOURNAMESPACE.YOURCLASSNAME").GetProperties();`

** Warning: above code is only work when your class declared in your assembly.

Comment: @ebbattulga Can I get class name at runtime instead of specifying it as typeof(Data).GetProperties()?

Comment: @ebbattulga Actually I don't know anything about class which I want to map.Even I don't know the name of class.I get that class with type of object and from that I need to populate everything.

Comment: @DTsawant - still not exactly sure, what you want. Maybe `yourObject.GetType().GetProperties()` will help you. Or maybe you want something like: `if (yourObject is Data) { handleData((Data)yourObject); } else if (yourObject is Test) { handleTest((Test)yourObject); }` and so on.